# What is the advantage of this +20% quality and the base quality gem

Tags: path-of-exile

I was searching on trade for a corrupted lvl 21 molten strike and decided to compare quality +20% to normal one, and as far as I can see, there is no difference between them (appart for the price 3 chaos for base quality vs 90 c orbs)
Do you see or can point a difference between them?

[image: comparison pictures]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quality gives 1% increased fire damage per quality, so with 20% it is a 20% increased fire damage, as noted in the fifth row.

In the [wiki](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Skill_gem) you can find the effect of quality for every gem, as it change for every single gem.

Comment: Thanks, so de difference was there and I just failed to spot it